# Default redirect url in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, redirect

I have a Django project in /test

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/test/test/django.wsgi
```

It works fine , but in redirect page , like logout -> login , it goes to :

```
127.0.0.1/accounts/login
```

So I don't have this url , it must redirect to this instead:

```
127.0.0.1/test/accounts/login
```

I set this is **settings.py**:

```
LOGIN_URL = "/test/accounts/login/"
```

And my **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$',login,name="login"),
```

and it doesn't work again.

How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Can't answer your first question, but in regards to your second you should use the [`redirect` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) with the view or model name to construct the URL. This way, the changing the URL in your `urls.py` will change it everywhere in your  codebase. Use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) or the `url` template tag for cases where you  only want the url -- not the redirect.

Comment: @J.DavidSmith yes , you are right , about the CreateView I should change direct address to reverse. but about the login , I add that in urls.py : url(r'^accounts/login/$',login,name="login"), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `SUB_SITE` to your settings.py:

```
# settings.py
SUB_SITE = "/test/"
```

And then in `settings.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^%s/' % settings.SUB_SITE, include('urls_subsite')),
)
```

More on it:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

Another option is to use this peace of code in `urls.py`:

```
if settings.URL_PREFIX:
    prefixed_urlpattern = []
    for pat in urlpatterns:
        pat.regex = re.compile(r"^%s/%s" % (settings.URL_PREFIX[1:], pat.regex.pattern[1:]))
        prefixed_urlpattern.append(pat)
    urlpatterns = prefixed_urlpattern
```

More on it:

- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2129/

But I personly think that the first solution is much better.

Comment: this variable is defined for Django? or I should use it manually is codes?

Comment: @MortezaIpo: Manually

Comment: @MortezaIpo: All that you have in `urls_subsite` (in my example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you should run a "sub" site within the same process by rewriting the patterns like the answer by @IgorChubin suggests, *that* should be an [app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

If you *really* want to have two sites running on the same domain, *even if they both use Django*, run *separate* (virtual)servers.

If you really must do this, use the *server config* to rewrite a specific url and run separate processes

IMO, the obvious options would be to:

- create a prefixed app within the project, or;
- create a subdomain

Then possibly use the Django sites framework to merge administrative tasks for the latter option.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer I use is,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect 
# hook for testing in local server, compatible with server deployment
def redirect_to_xkcd( request, everythingelse ):
    return HttpResponseRedirect( "/"+everythingelse, request )
```

and add this line to the urlpatterns

```
url(r'test/(?P<everythingelse>.+)', redirect_to_xkcd ),
```